# Brackets in \subsection titles

Tags: brackets

The mathematical text

```
    ${\mathbb Z}[\sqrt{2}]$
```

works perfectly well within the general text, but I want it as a subsection title. However,

```
    \subsection${\mathbb Z}[\sqrt{2}]$
```

produces the error message "Missing $ inserted" when I try to typeset.

Further investigation shows that brackets within \subsection titles will typeset when not within math delimiters $ $, but not correctly. For example,

```
\subsection{This is [rubbish]}
```

will produce the subsection number, followed by just a close bracket ] (in the same bold font size as the subsection number), and then "This is [rubbish]" in the ordinary text font on the next line.

So is there any way to include brackets [ ] in a \subsection title, either within or outside math delimiters?

Comment: You're doing it wrong, since you're missing the braces `\subsection{...}`.

Comment: `\subsection{$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$}` will work flawlessly. And `\subsection{This is [rubbish]}` raises no error at all. If you get errors from them, please add some information about the class you're using.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

The following works:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\section{$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$}

\subsection{This is [rubbish]}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that the mandatory argument of section must be given within braces (`{...}`) and that `\mathbb` is not a declaration: it must be used as `\mathbb{CORRECT}`, not as `{\mathbb INCORRECT}`.

As you can see, there is nothing special with brackets, as long as you've put the argument within braces, as usual.

## Brackets in the optional argument

In case you need brackets inside an *optional argument*—which is not the case in the question—*then* there is a trick: you can wrap the whole within braces, like `[{stuff with brackets}]`. For instance:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section[{For TOC [with brackets]}]{Long title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As shown in the screenshot, this uses the title `For TOC [with brackets]` in the table of contents (also in headers when using a class such as `book`), and `Long title` in the text. The following would be incorrect:

```latex
\section[For TOC [with brackets]]{Long title}
```

[image]

Indeed, in that case:

- the optional argument seen by `\section` would be `For TOC [with brackets` (in the absence of braces, the first closing bracket found after the beginning of the optional argument marks the end of this argument);
- the mandatory argument would be `]` (first brace-balanced token list following the optional argument—only one token here), and
- `{Long title}` would be interpreted as plain text following the section (simple text written inside a useless group).

Comment: Thank you, I have copied and pasted this, but get the same result as before.  Could this be because I am using a style file supplied by a publisher, and they may have put something in that messes things up?

Comment: If you compile this exact code and nothing else, it should work. If it doesn't, I'm afraid it's an installation problem. But since you mention a style file we don't know, there appears to be a very important unknown that is not in your question, and I can't do anything about it, sorry.

Comment: Don't you mean `{[stuff with brackets]}`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I really meant what I wrote: `[{stuff with brackets}]`. Try the `\tableofcontents` with `\section[{For TOC [with brackets]}]{Long title}`. Then remove the pair of braces inside the optional argument and enjoy. :-) (this breaks not only the TOC entry, but also the in-text title in an interesting way, BTW)

Comment: That's a clearer example.  The one you've given in the answer doesn't take into consideration the fact that the optional heading [in brackets] can cause problems,  Newbies often aren't aware that such options exist.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The question *doesn't mention any optional argument,* I only added this remark as a bonus. There is no problem whatsoever with square brackets in the mandatory argument, AFAIK; my answer shows that the supposedly problematic titles work perfectly there. So, frankly, I fail to see what I should add to satisfy the OP or anyone else here.

Comment: Nice addition.  Thanks.

Comment: It does seem to be a problem with the publisher's installation.  I have now copied and pasted the original suggestion into one of my documents not using a style file, and it works.  But what I am getting when I use it in the document with the style file is very similar to what @frougon shows happens when you use the incorrect format for "Brackets in the optional argument" (even though there is no optional argument).

Answer (score 0):

I have now finally cured the problem, by putting a \mbox round each bracket:

```
\subsection{$\mathbb{Z}\mbox{[}\sqrt{2}\mbox{]}$}
```

But the problem does seem to be specific to the publisher's style file, since I don't need to go to such lengths with any LaTeX code not using this style file.